# Error trying to install packer in neovim

Tags: neovim, packer

Inspired by [this video by The Primeagen](https://youtu.be/w7i4amO_zaE), I'm trying to install packer.nvim by following [the instructions on its github page](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim). I did this:

```bash
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim\
 ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim
```

Then I created this `~/.config/nvim/lua/packer.lua`:

```lua
-- This file can be loaded by calling `lua require('plugins')` from your init.vim

-- Only required if you have packer configured as `opt`
vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]

return require('packer').startup(function(use)
  -- Packer can manage itself
  use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
end)
```

When I try to source `packer.lua`, I receive the following error:

```
Error detected while processing /home/michael/.config/nvim/lua/packer.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /home/michael/.config/nvim/lua/packer.lua:6: loop or previous error loading module 'packer'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /home/michael/.config/nvim/lua/packer.lua:6: in main chunk
```

Neovim v0.9.0-dev-530+gde90a8bfe is installed from the `.deb` file from its Web site. OS is Ubuntu 22.04.1. Lua is version 5.2.4.

I know no lua yet.

If someone could explain what's going on and what I can do to fix it, I'd deeply appreciate it.

Comment: Sounds like the `require('packer')` is trying to load the same file you sourced (since it's called `packer.lua`). Perhaps try a different name?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Well... that was a simple-enough fix. Thank you so much. I'm wondering why it worked for the maker of the video but not for me.

Comment: Based on https://github.com/ThePrimeagen/init.lua/blob/master/lua/theprimeagen/packer.lua, the filepaths are different (compare `theprimeagen/packer.lua` to `packer.lua`)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Is it because he's using a directory named after himself under the "lua" directory? It'd be simple enough to trash my setup and start over. I haven't committed to neovim.

Comment: Effectively, yes. (I'm assuming NeoVim + Lua use some sort of path-based module system… Having never used either, I'm not certain that's the case.)