# Error when trying to set a color scheme

Tags: neovim, colorscheme

My `init.vim` is placed in `~/.config/nvim/` and has the following in it:

```
call plug#begin()

Plug 'folke/tokyonight.nvim', { 'branch': 'main' }
Plug 'nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua'
Plug 'nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons'

call plug#end()

" plugin configs
lua require('nerd-tree')
lua require('tokyonight')
```

I also have the directory `~/.config/nvim/lua/` and in there I have the files `nerd-tree.lua` and `tokyonight.lua`. Inside `tokyonight.lua` I have the line `vim.cmd[[colorscheme tokyonight]]`. The plugin is successfully installed and also nerd-tree is working fine, it is just the color scheme. When I open `nvim` I get the error message

```
Error detected while processing /Users/nickeisenberg/.config/nvim/init.vim:
line   12:
E5108: Error executing lua /Users/nickeisenberg/.config/nvim/lua/tokyonight.lua:1: Vim(colorscheme):E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: ...share/nvim/plugged/tokyonight.nvim/colors/t
okyonight.lua:1: loop or previous error loading module 'tokyonight'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ...share/nvim/plugged/tokyonight.nvim/colors/tokyonight.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'cmd'
        /Users/nickeisenberg/.config/nvim/lua/tokyonight.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'cmd'
        /Users/nickeisenberg/.config/nvim/lua/tokyonight.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I also tried the gruvbox color scheme and I got the same error message. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Usage](https://github.com/folke/tokyonight.nvim#-usage), you need only `:colorscheme tokyonight` or `vim.cmd[[colorscheme tokyonight]]` directly. It's probably not worth putting in a separate special file (and if it is, I recommend `plugin/` directories on `'runtimepath'`, since they are executed automatically).

The error looks like `require('tokyonight')` triggered loading `colors/tokyonight.lua` via the colorscheme command, which contains the same require, thereby introducing a cycle. The latter require is intended to load the plugin code, but instead finds your code because they have the same filename.

In short, [don't name your custom files after plugins](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/39602/10604).

Comment: I ended up realizing that after I posted. However I tried both things that you suggested, either just putting `colorscheme tokyonight` inside my `init.vim` and also creating a plugin directory within the lua directory and doing both ways lead to the same result where the color scheme does not seem to be loading correctly. It just gives a dark background and dark blue text. See both of these for what I mean https://imgur.com/a/EbMLhzq, https://imgur.com/a/GCdjZ7S. Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: @alpastor that I don't have an answer for.

Comment: If you are curious, it was because the stock mac terminal does not support the colors needed for, what I'm guessing is, most neovim color schemes. I downloaded iTerm2 and everything worked perfectly with what you said above.

Comment: That's because Terminal.app does not support truecolor (aka 24-bit color). iTerm2, Alacritty, etc., all do.