# Error when trying to set Kanagawa colorscheme

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, init.vim

I installed [Kanagawa plugin](https://github.com/rebelot/kanagawa.nvim) using vim-plug.

When I tried to change the colorscheme with:

```
:colorscheme kanagawa
```

I got the following error :

```
>- Error detected while processing /home/mmip/.local/share/nvim/site/plugged/kanagawa.nvim/colors/kanagawa.vim:                                          
>- line    1:                                                                                                                                            
>E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: loop or previous error loading module 'kanagawa'                                                        
>- stack traceback:                                                                                                                                      
>           [C]: in function 'require'                                                                                                                    
>           [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
```

I have been trying to figure it out looking to [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/39616/error-when-trying-to-set-a-color-scheme) (very similar question), but eventually I didn't manage to solve the problem.

Here is how I installed the plugin using vim-plug : in my `init.vim` file I added:

```
Plug 'rebelot/kanagawa.nvim'
```

Inside the

```
call plug#begin('~/.local/share/nvim/site/plugged
" ...
call plug#end()
```

Then I called:

```
:PlugInstall.
```

My version of nvim is v0.6.1.

Comment: Welcome to Vim. It seems that the plugin is installed in `nvim/site` where I would expect it in `nvim-data/plugged`. Could you share with use how did you install the plugin using Vim-Plug? Could you share your version of Neovim?

Comment: [Please don’t post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/). You can [edit] to add the error message.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt, I installed the plugin by calling PlugInstall after adding ```Plug 'rebelot/kanagawa.nvim``` inside the "call plug" part at the top of my init.vim file (I edited my question with more details). I use nvim v0.6.1.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to reproduce the problem. How did you activate the colorscheme?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt, I activated the colorscheme with ```:colorscheme kanagawa```.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) I suppose you saw my answer. I believe your problem is the version of Neovim you are using :-/

Comment: Yes, I saw it, I was looking for information about updating my nvim version. Seems a bit scary ! Especially if I have to redo my config in LUA... I have to investigate more before taking a decision. Thanks a lot anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my test the [kanagawa](https://github.com/rebelot/kanagawa.nvim) `colorscheme` requiers Neovim 8.0.

It seems to me that Neovim 6.1 doesn't yet support `colorscheme` developed in Lua.

Apparently kanagawa `colorscheme` requiers some standard highlighting groups that are not yet standard in Neovim 7.0.

I suggest to migrate to Neovim 8.0 or above.